# Help me create a script that runs when keyboard is undocked

Tags: scripts, keyboard, udev

I have made the following

```
 # Saved as /etc/udev/rules.d/81-MSSP3-dock.rules


# Microsoft Surface Pro Keyboard
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="045e", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="07e3, GOTO="MSSP3_rules"
GOTO="MSSP3_rules_end"

LABEL="MSSP3_rules"
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/home/joshuarobison/Documents/Scripts/landscape.sh"
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/home/joshuarobison/Documents/Scripts/portrait.sh"

LABEL="MSSP3_rules_end"
```

my udev is as follows

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [2672.635429] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:045E:07E3.0012/input/input303/event3 (input)
ACTION=remove
BACKSPACE=guess
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-event-kbd /dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Surface_Type_Cover-event-kbd
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event3
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:045E:07E3.0012/input/input303/event3
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=Surface_Type_Cover
ID_MODEL_ENC=Surface\x20Type\x20Cover
ID_MODEL_ID=07e3
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0
ID_REVISION=0307
ID_SERIAL=Microsoft_Surface_Type_Cover
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Microsoft
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Microsoft
ID_VENDOR_ID=045e
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/45e/7e3:usb-0000:00:14.0-3
MAJOR=13
MINOR=67
SEQNUM=4374
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:power-switch:
USEC_INITIALIZED=2297576881
XKBLAYOUT=jp
XKBMODEL=pc105
```

The landscape and portrait scripts already work.  I know that the problem is in the udev rules somehow.  When I undock and dock the keyboard the script is not run.

Even if the portrait or landscape.sh scripts are just a simple echo command, nothing happens.

Comment: please look at this example: https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will set up the Microsoft SP3 so that when the keyboard is removed it switches to portrait mode.  The scripts ensure that the active stylus and capacitive touch orientation is correct.

Thank you to @george udeson for the link to the tutorial which helped me write this.

UDEV rules

```
# Saved as /etc/udev/rules.d/81-MSSP3-dock.rules

# Microsoft Surface Pro Keyboard

ACTION=="add" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="07e3" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e" \
, ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" \
, ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/joshuarobison/.Xauthority" \
, RUN+="//home/joshuarobison/Documents/Scripts/landscape.sh"

ACTION=="remove" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="07e3" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e" \
, ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" \
, ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/joshuarobison/.Xauthority" \
, RUN+="//home/joshuarobison/Documents/Scripts/portrait.sh"
```

portrait.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
#Portrait
xrandr -o left
  xinput set-prop "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
  xinput set-prop "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
  xsetwacom set "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05 Pen stylus" Rotate ccw
```

landscape.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
#landscape

  xrandr -o normal
  xinput set-prop "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  xinput set-prop "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  xsetwacom set "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05 Pen stylus" Rotate 0
```

After creating the udev rules file do not forget to run

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

Comment: Sorry for the late action

Comment: :) no problem bro, have nice day